# image selection des not work in ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, android-camera

i am trying to open the photolibrary of android to select images using ionic 2.
here is the code of the home.ts in witch the camera plugin is used.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Camera} from '@ionic-native/camera';
@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
   image640:any;
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public camera : Camera) 
   {

   }

openGallery()
{
    var options = {
quality: 100,
sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
correctOrientation: true,
};
   this.camera.getPicture(
  options 
   ).then(
      (imageData)=>
   {
      this.image640 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+imageData;
   },
   (err) => 
   {
      console.log(err);
   }
);
}

}
```

And the code of the home.html is below :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title align="center">
   Blank
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <img src="image640" *ngIf="image640"/>

<Button align="center" ion-button (click)="openGallery()">Open 
Gallery</Button>

</ion-content>
```

but when i click on the opengallery button, the android library is opened but when i select an image, a blank screen appear during about 8 seconds, and after that, the it is the rootpage that is displayed. Then i cannot see the selected image in my page.
can somebody help ?

Answer (score 0):

Set options

```
var options = {
  quality: 100,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true,
};
```

Then select photos like this

```
 this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imagePath) => {

  // Special handling for Android library
  if (this.platform.is('android') && sourceType === 
 this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) { //when selecting from library

        //your code goes here
  } else { //when capturing by camera
      //your code goes here
  }
```

Comment: thanks @Iris_geek. But i tried it. it does not work at all. i edited the code. you can see it babove in the post.

Comment: I just copied your code and it is working fine. I don't know where you're doing wrong.

Comment: do you have the statusbar plugin installed ?

Comment: Yes. That's a default one

Comment: OK. now it works fine on my project. I can take a picture and select a photo from the library. But how to select multiple images from the gallery ?

Comment: I haven't tried multiple, but I think one should use imagepicker cordova plugin to get it done.